# HTMLPurifier - Editing target tags

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I want to add all A elements target="_blank" attribute or change value to "_blank" if different. Is this possible with HTMLPurifier? I couldn't find any information or documentation about this on the internet. 
For example;

Input

```
<a href="some_url">Link 1</a> 
<a href="some_url" target="_self">Link 2</a>
<a href="some_url" target="_blank">Link 3</a>
```

Current Output

```
<a href="some_url">Link 1</a> 
<a href="some_url">Link 2</a> 
<a href="some_url" target="_blank">Link 3</a>
```

Desired Output

```
<a href="some_url" target="_blank">Link 1</a> 
<a href="some_url" target="_blank">Link 2</a>
<a href="some_url" target="_blank">Link 3</a>
```

Current Configs

```
$config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href|target]');
$config->set('Attr.AllowedFrameTargets', array('_blank'));
```

I am not asking 'How can I allow custom tags?'. The problem is 'Can I manipulate attribute value with HTMLPurifier if value different than `_blank`?'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htmlpurifier custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464004/htmlpurifier-custom-attributes)

Comment: no its not, target tags allowed in my configs but htmlpurifier totally removes the tag if value different than predefined value. I don't like this. I am looking for changing attribute value or add attribute if not exist

Comment: Have you considered `HTML.TargetBlank`? It's only for outgoing links, but otherwise what you're looking for. If that's not enough, you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/2638640/245790, the "Point of reference" section is precisely about adding (or overwriting) `target="_blank"`.